# wordpress blog styling

Tags: wordpress, coding-style, wordpress-theming

I am looking for a tutorial on how to style my word press (hosted on word press) blog to look like my businesses home page.  I would like the links to work and look the same.  The site isn't completely styled in CSS, but can maybe move more of the styling to css from the HTML.  Can someone point me in the right direction where I need to start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, isn't there an upload theme section at wordpress.com? Anyways, you'll need to zip up your theme (after you make it) and upload it there. Also, here's a tutorial for making a basic theme.

http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

(that's not my blog by the way)